# Proper way of loading view and model in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

What is the proper way of loading a view and model in a MVC PHP application? Should I do it like Codeigniter where I just call `$this->load->model` or `$this->load->view` in a super Loader and load it from there? Or is that bad practice?

Comment: Probably what you are looking for : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156066/how-to-do-mvc-the-right-way